# How do you get a specific type from a data definition in an instance?

Tags: haskell

I'm going to assume that in the instance of `Fractal Mandelbrot`, in `escapeCount f (C comp3)` the `f` stands for `Mandelbrot` datatype. How would I access an element of that such as MaxIter. Do I just have to write definitions for each element that I could want?

```
  type MaxIter = Int
  type Row = Int 
  type Col = Int 
  data Complex = C Double Double                    deriving (Show,Eq)
  data Mandelbrot = M MaxIter Row Col Complex Complex    deriving (Eq)

  class (Show f) => Fractal f where 
  escapeCount :: f -> Complex -> Int

  instance Fractal Mandelbrot where
              escapeCount f (C comp3) = <- I assume this means that comp3 is of type C?
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the specifics of what you're trying to accomplish, but you can access the parts of these datatypes with pattern matching:

```
instance Fractal Mandelbrot where
    escapeCount (M maxIter row col c1 c2) c3 = ...
```

This makes the parts available within the function as the variables `maxIter`, `row`, `col`, etc.

You can do as much pattern matching as needed:

```
escapeCount (M maxIter row col (C real1 imag1) (C real2 imag2)) (C real3 imag3) = ...
```

Also, I recommend the [`Complex` datatype from `Data.Complex`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Complex.html#t:Complex), instead of making your own.  It already has a `Num` instance, so you can add, subtract, etc. them just like with normal numbers, as well as a base of useful functions.

Comment: Thanks and unfortunately I have to make my own complex. Also, escapeCount has a signature which I'm trying to implement under instance but how do I access the second "Parameter" it takes? Also when I tried to do pattern matching it said Variable not in scope?